# "No such file or directory" trying to execute linux binary on Android device

Tags: android, linux, native

I built a native linux ARM binary using the Android GCC toolchain (plain linux, no android or NDK).

I connected, from my PC, via adb shell, to a tablet running Android 4.
I "adb push"'ed that binary into /system/bin on that device, hoping I would get it to execute there. I marked it executable with chmod 777.

If I try to execute it, I would get "No such file or directory".

Further info:
The little program uses fc and fm libs. Since the ARM toolchain does not appear to have crt1, which, from an example I found, normally contains the startup code, we searched through files containing it in the android build, found crtbegin_dynamic and crtend_dynamic, but for _static equivalent, one of the pair was missing, so I did not pass -static to GCC. It was built with "-nostdlib".

What could be the problem(s)?

Comment: You need to use nm or similar to find the dependencies of your executable, but realistically you should use only the NDK gcc to build for Android unless you insist on doing things the hard way.  **Please note that this question has nothing to do with missing libraries for the development machine**, despite mysteriously having attracted a popular answer on that entirely distinct subject.

Answer (score 47):

If you are working on a 64-bit platform like Ubuntu 64, then this tip may help you solve the issue. Just try to get the i386 32-bit compatibility libraries installed simply with 
apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

It worked great for me. Let me know if you are stuck in same trouble.

**For Ubuntu 13.10 or greater**

As aditya said in the comments to this answer:

As of Ubuntu 13.10, one has to run this now:
`sudo apt-get install lib32z1`, you may need to get the C++ stdlibs too, with this: `sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6`

Comment: As of Ubuntu 13.10, looks like ia32-libs has been replaced by the following package. One has to run this now:

`sudo apt-get install lib32z1`

I had to get the C++ stdlibs too, with this: 

`sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6`

Comment: While this may have helped other people get the adb executable running on their ubuntu linux system, it does not appear to have anything at all to do with the question asked, which concerned **running a binary under android itself**.  Needless to say, Android does not utilize a debian-style packaging system.

Answer (score 2):

To amend aditya's comment above, you can also use the following for the C++ stdlibs in Ubuntu 13.10:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5 libstdc++6:i386
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question asked, which concerns running an executable on Android itself - a linux that does not utilize the debian packaging system.